# How to configure Debug.WriteLine output file?

Tags: c#

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` is used for tracing.

Funilly a file `C:\Users\Public\Documents\UserNameFromProgramContext\ProgramName.asserts` is created on my machine, but not on that of another developer.

I only wanted `Debug.WriteLine` for output in the Output Window of VS.

Where is it possible to configure the place where `Debug.WriteLine` writes to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("c:\\temp\\test.txt"));
Debug.AutoFlush = true;
Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

so just use the Listeners collection to manipulate where debug data is written to

Comment: Thx, was not completly the point, but is surely helpful. The problem was that in app.config there was a <system.diagnostics> <assert logfilename="..."/> . Maybe from a previous used log component which was replaced long ago....